# jQueryMobile scrolls the parent page when iFramed - how?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, iframe

If I iFrame a page that runs using jQueryMobile, once the page has loaded, it will scroll down to the top of that iFrame. If I then open a lightbox, the page will scroll down to the lightbox's position. Note: this is on iOS devices in particular.

For example, go here on your iPhone: http://jsfiddle.net/morgoe/NSUnJ/
Scroll down to 'photo lighbox' and click on one of the images. The entire page will scroll down to the lighbox.

How is jQueryMobile manipulating the scroll position of the parent frame?

```
won't let me submit without some code.
```

Comment: `window.top.scrollTo` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

They're using

```
window.location.hash = '#edit';
```

to scroll to the position of element with the id 'edit'. Clever.